# SQL - How can I hard-code the time of a date value in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following value and need to hard-code the time to a new value:

Currently:

> 2016-10-11 06:00:00.000

New:

> 2016-10-11 21:00:00.000

This must be with a SELECT statement due to system restrictions.

The input values could be any hour, minute or seconds (00:00:00 to 23:59:59), but the output value should always be a hard-coded value of 21:00:00

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question.

Comment: Are you trying to calculate `21:00:00` on today's date? (`select DateAdd( hour, 21, Cast( Cast( GetDate() as Date ) as DateTime ) )`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out with the following statement:

> CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(20),DateCreated, 20),10) + '
>   09:00:00', 120) AS DateCreatedHardCoded

Broken Down:

1. CONVERT changes the date into a NVARCHAR string with the format of "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss"
2. LEFT takes the converted string and cuts off once it reaches 10 characters from the left - "2016-10-11"
3. CONVERT applies the concatenation of 2016-10-11 + a hardcoded value of "09:00:00" into a datetime of "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss"
4. AS applies this result to the new field "DateCreatedHardCoded"

Answer (score 1):

```
select dateadd(HOUR, 15, '2016-10-11 06:00:00.000') as new, 
       TO_DATE('2016-10-11 06:00:00.000') AS current
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dateadd to add hours in datetime.

E.g.

```
select dateadd(hh, 15, '2016-10-11 06:00:00.000'); -- output 2016-10-11 21:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this:

```
select dateadd(hour, 21, cast(datecol as date))
```

The `cast(datecol as date)` removes the time component.  The `dateadd()` then adds 21 hours to the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select SUBSTRING(CAST(Currently AS varchar),0,11)+' 21:00:00.000' AS New from tableName
```